# Resolve type bound ToConstant with Ninject

Tags: ninject

I have a class with 3 parameters in the constructor registered in Ninject with "ToConstant". I want to get this instance without providing constructor parameters because was bound as a single instance. If this possible?

I understand, if I register a type as a single instance, Ninject should not ask for any constructor parameters because there is nothing to instantiate.

Code snippet follows:

```
//create object
var singleInstance = new WhateverObject(param1, param2, param3);
//bind object ToConstant 
_kernel.Bind<WhateverObject>().ToConstant(singleInstance);
//resolve type
var instanceToRetrieve = _kernel.Get<WhateverObject>();
```

Statement above (resolve type) crashes because WhateverObject has no parameterless constructor and ninject needs param1, param2 and param3. The point is, why Ninject needs those parameters if object was registered as a single instance? How do we request to ninject a type registered as singleton?

Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to bind the type as constant (singleton):

```
public void BindToConstant<T1, T2>(Dictionary<string, object> arguments = null) where T2 : T1
        {
            if (!_kernel.GetBindings(typeof(T1)).Any())
            {
                var constant = _kernel.Bind<T1>().To<T2>().InSingletonScope();
                if (arguments != null && arguments.Count > 0)
                {
                    arguments.ForEach(p =>
                    {
                        constant.WithConstructorArgument(p.Key, p.Value);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

Where arguments is a dictionary where they key is the name of constructor argument and value is the value of the argument, so you can call this method with a flexible amount of parameters.

Hope it helps to somebody with the same problem!